# Strange behavior of the Microsoft Bluetooth stack under windows 7

Tags: bluetooth, serial-port, zebra-printers, hyperterminal, intermec

I'm linking some Zebra, Intermec printers, etc via bluetooth ...

The behaviour is:

1. The printer is linked, for exmple, to the port COM9
2. I send data to the printer and it works fine
3. After printing, I connect via Hyperterminal to send commands to the printer, and it shows that the port COM9 is in use
4. If I try again to print from another source, like notepad, word, etc,  it works fine

Is there any way to find out what is using the port COM9 that is not letting the Hyperterminal to connect properly?

Thank you.

---

*Bluethood Drivers Version: 6.1.7601.17607*

*Date Bluethood  Drivers: 21/06/2006*

Comment: When you say you send data to the printer, is that using Windows printing service/spooler? Does the Windows spooler release the com port/printer when it has finished? Quite possible it hangs on to it ready for the next print job. Before you do the first print (#2), can you connect to printer using hyperterminal?

Comment: - When you say you send data to the printer, is that using Windows printing service/spooler? ** Yes I'am using Windows service, like you print thing in Word** The issue appears the fist time that I start windows. The fist time that I try to use the printer happen that I it explained before.

Comment: In that case I imagine the spooler is keeping the com port open to the printer, preventing you from accessing it. If you want to print, your will have to do it via Windows printing facilities.

Comment: i.e. it is nothing to do with the bluetooth stack providing the COM port.

Comment: Thank for your answer, I going to research more about Windows spooler.